A TCP client in Go - what to choose: conn.Write(data) or Fprintf(conn, data)?
I am writing a little TCP client, which sends a "query" to home music server and gets answers. There also are answers emitted by the server with no queries ("broadcasted" - like manually changing the music volume on the server).
I have found two ways to make TCP client in Go - one uses conn.Write(data) and then conn.Read(buffer) - and the other one uses Fprintf(conn, data) and then bufio module to process answers.
I wonder what are the grounds for using the first or second method. In what cases is one method chosen and in which is the other?
GreetingS!
I was trying both and all seems to work, but I am beginner in Go and I would like to learn right patterns.

conn.Write writes a []byte to the connection. Fprintf(conn, data) uses the string data as a format string and writes that to the connection. The two calls do very different things.

Use the method that does what you need it to do. If you don’t need to write something via a formatted string, you don’t need Fprintf. Most of the time you wouldn’t be using the connection directly anyway, you use bufio or helpers in io (the concepts are the same in most languages and not specific to Go, they only differ in what they are called)

Well, maybe I am wrong, but on my side there is no difference if I send a command (which looks like: server://player/get_now_playing_media?pid=player_id ) - both method will achieve the serwer and there will be response from the server. The quiesion is which is more correct?

There is always going to be many ways to achieve the same end result. Pick the one which is most clear and consistent in your code.
